# How to use SQLcipher on c#

Tags: c#, encryption, sqlcipher

I realised a program in order to save login and password in Winform c#.
I used sqlite to save the data but with DB Browser for SQLite I can view all my data :\

I read with sqlcipher I can set a password for the connection to the DB in order to protect the data.
My question is how ?
I installed the NuGetpackage sqlite-net-sqlcipher, add the file SQLite.cs from the below website to my solution explorer and to my packages.config
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Encrypted passwords can be decrypted again. You should hash them instead.

Comment: It actually shouldn't be a problem if someone can see the data because you should not be storing passwords in the first place. What you should be doing is hashing the password when the user registers and saving that, then hashing the password when the user logs in and comparing the result to what's in the database. The original password cannot be easily regenerated from the hash.